# How to conditionally show table row based on drop-down selection?

Tags: java, html

I searched high and low and still can't figure this out.  I am creating a web to lead form and I have a drop down field called Referral, with choices of Internet, Friend, etc.

If they select Friend, I would like a table row to appear underneath called Friend Name, where they can enter their friend's name.  If something else is selected this would be hidden.

Please see the code below.  Thank you!

```html
<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Referral: <span class="required" style="color: #ff0000;">*</span></span></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;" width="35%">
<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
<select id="referral_c" name="referral_c" tabindex="1" onchange="show_referral();"> 
<option selected="selected" value="Internet">Internet</option> 
<option value="Friend" id="friend_click">Friend</option>
  
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;" width="15%">
<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Friend Name: <span class="friend" style="color: #ff0000;"></span></span></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;" width="35%">
<span class="friend" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
<input id="friend_name_c" type="text" name="friend_name_c" /></span></td>
</tr>
```

```js
function show_referral(){
 var referral = document.getElementById("referral_c");
 var referral_text = referral.options[referral.selectedIndex].text;
 
 $("#friend_click").click(function () {
  $(".friend").show();
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would be remiss if I didn't recommend putting the styles in a separate css file. Be that as it may, one possible solution is:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Referral: <span class="required" style="color: #ff0000;">*</span></span>
    </td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;" width="35%">
      <span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <select id="referral_c" name="referral_c" tabindex="1" onchange="show_referral();" > 
          <option selected="selected" value="Internet">Internet</option> 
          <option value="Friend" id="friend_click">Friend</option>
        </select>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="friend_row" style="display: none;">
    <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;" width="15%">
      <span class="friend" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Friend Name: <span class="friend" style="color: #ff0000;"></span></span>
    </td>
    <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;" width="35%">
      <span class="friend" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
      <input id="friend_name_c" type="text" name="friend_name_c" /></span>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
function show_referral() {
    var referral = document.getElementById("referral_c");
    var referral_text = referral.options[referral.selectedIndex].text;

    if (referral_text === "Friend") {
        $("#friend_row").show();
    } else {
        $("#friend_row").hide();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: complete working page

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
    <tr>
   <td>
     <span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Referral: <span class="required" style="color: #ff0000;">*</span></span>
   </td>
   <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;" width="35%">
     <span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <select id="referral_c" name="referral_c" tabindex="1" onchange="show_referral();" > 
      <option selected="selected" value="Internet">Internet</option> 
      <option value="Friend" id="friend_click">Friend</option>
    </select>
     </span>
   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="friend_row" style="display: none;">
   <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;" width="15%">
     <span class="friend" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Friend Name: <span class="friend" style="color: #ff0000;"></span></span>
   </td>
   <td style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;" width="35%">
     <span class="friend" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
     <input id="friend_name_c" type="text" name="friend_name_c" /></span>
   </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   function show_referral() {
    var referral = document.getElementById( "referral_c" );
    var referral_text = referral.options[referral.selectedIndex].text;

    if (referral_text === "Friend") {
     $( "#friend_row" ).show();
    } else {
     $( "#friend_row" ).hide();
    }
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working.  I think the problem is with the onchange command. I put an alert('Test'); inside of the java, and get no response.

Comment: Thank you!  I finally figured out the problem was the src at the top:  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js".  Once I changed it to that it worked perfectly.  Thanks again!